# AWS EC2 CPU credit balance keeps dropping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

I am new to the AWS cloud world.
My AWS EC2 CPU credit balance keeps dropping and when it reaches 0, the web site became extremely slow.
What did I do wrong?
I am using t2.medium.
Thank you.

I tried from t2.micro (free tier) to t2.small to t2.medium.
The issue appears to repeat itself.
I would imagine that I need to keep upgrading my ec2 instance because my web site is too big?

Comment: You need to choose a T instance class that accrues credits faster than you're using them.  If you find that your CPU usage is less bursty and more consistent, you should be using an M, C, or R instance class which doesn't have CPU credits and instead provides consistent performance (and costs more)

Comment: If this is unexpected, you might start by looking at what is running on your EC2 instance (using Linux `top` command, or Windows task manager) to understand what exactly is using so much CPU.

Comment: Thank you, @erik258. If my CPU credit balance keeps dropping during peak hours and keep rising during off-peak hours ( I am hosting a major PHP-based web site there), is this somewhat acceptable? Or should I aim for a setup where the CPU credit balance stays flat. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, @MarkB. It's php that consumed a lot of CPU and there is limited things I can do to make it consume less CPU.

Comment: "dropping peak and keep rising off-peak"  You can turn on [Unlimited Mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances-unlimited-mode.html) and pay a flat rate of $0.05 per vcpu hour when you exceed your burst balance.   Will that be more expensive than an instance with dedicated cpu?  Perhaps - depends on how much cpu you use.

Comment: See: [Burstable performance instances - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-performance-instances.html)